# Run Unity standalone in Headless Mode whilst capturing screenshots

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rendering, headless

I need to create a unity project which runs in Headless mode (using the -batchmode command), but it must capture screenshots e.g. every one second and write them out to a file.

I understand that in headless mode you need to forcefully call Camera.Render() in order for anything to be rendered.

It seems that time freezes after the first screenshot is captured. The first screenshot looks absolutely correct, but all subsequent screenshots are identical to the first, implying that time has frozen.

What do I need to do to ensure that the scene updates correctly over time and that the camera is able to render every second?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets
{
    public class Particles : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private const float screenshotEvery = 1.0f;
        private float timerCount = 0f;
        private float elapsedSecond;
        private const float maxElapsedSecond = 20;
        private string screenshotsDirectory = "UnityHeadlessRenderingScreenshots";
        public Camera camOV;
        public RenderTexture currentRT;

        // Use this for initialization
        public void Start ()
        {
            Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
            if (Directory.Exists(screenshotsDirectory))
            {
                Directory.Delete(screenshotsDirectory, true);
            }
            if (!Application.isEditor)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(screenshotsDirectory);
                camOV.targetTexture = currentRT;
            }

        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        public void Update ()
        {
            elapsedSecond += Time.deltaTime;
            timerCount += Time.deltaTime;
            if (Application.isEditor)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (elapsedSecond <= maxElapsedSecond)
            {
                if (timerCount >= screenshotEvery)
                {
                    TakeScreenShot();
                    timerCount = 0f;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Quit();
            }
        }

        public void TakeScreenShot()
        {
            RenderTexture.active = camOV.targetTexture;
            camOV.Render();
            Texture2D imageOverview = new Texture2D(camOV.targetTexture.width, camOV.targetTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
            imageOverview.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, camOV.targetTexture.width, camOV.targetTexture.height), 0, 0);
            imageOverview.Apply();
            RenderTexture.active = currentRT;

            // Encode texture into PNG
            byte[] bytes = imageOverview.EncodeToPNG();

            // save in memory
            string filename = elapsedSecond + ".png";
            var path = screenshotsDirectory + "/" + filename;
            File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);

        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You left few things out. What is `currentRT`? How is it initialized?

Comment: @Programmer Sorry, I have added the full script to the question. They are assigned via the editor (dragging+dropping onto the public variables in the script)

Comment: Ok. I see the update now. Are you testing this through the Editor or Build? What command line are you exactly passing in?

Comment: @Programmer This will work in the editor, but not as a Windows standalone. I am giving it the command line parameter: "-batchmode" which puts it in headless mode. All I need to to be able to capture an output from the cameras without the output being displayed on the screen. The desktop must be fully visible and usable (hence headless)

Comment: But I am asking if the done is currently being done through Editor or Standalone....

Comment: @Programmer Apologies, I think I may be misunderstanding your question. I am testing this through Standalone.

Comment: Ok. I will see if can replicate that same problem.

Comment: It seems like the act of calling Camera.Render() causes the scene/time to stop advancing. You can e.g. call .Render() at 10 seconds, and it will output a correct image, however if you subsequently call .Render() at 15 seconds, the same image as before will be output. All subsequent Render()s will result in identical images.

Comment: From CMD, I ran it like this "test.exe -batchmode" but no problem. It took screenshot every second. Although, I am using a heavy modified version of your code. What makes you think it is freezing? All images/screenshots are really the-same? Are you sure that something is moving your scene? If nothing is moving, the images would be the-same...

Comment: @Programmer I have a particle system in the middle of my scene so that I can easily see if the scene is updating. All of the images which are output are exactly the same. They all look like this: http://i.imgur.com/l1b0X3C.png The particle system just flings particles into the air, and it clearly works as anticipated in the editor. Would you mind kindly sending me your project, and I can do likewise?

Comment: You have RenderTexture plugged into your camera? I will leave my code as an answer instead because the project consist of other Projects and it's huge.

Comment: @Programmer Yes, that's correct

Comment: Ok Try the code the answer I am about to post in a second. Let me know if that works. If that doesn't work then send me the project. I will take a look at it.

Comment: @Programmer OK will do, many thanks

Comment: Well, good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One advice I would give you about taking screenshots is to wait for [`WaitForEndOfFrame`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForEndOfFrame.html) before taking the screenshot.

You said that you want to capture screenshot every second and save this. This should be done in coroutine not in the Update function.

Something like this in a coroutine function:

```
WaitForEndOfFrame waitForFrame = new WaitForEndOfFrame();
WaitForSeconds waitForTime = new WaitForSeconds(1);//1 second

while (true)
{
    //Wait for frame
    yield return waitForFrame;

    Increment timer

    Capture and save Screenshot

    Save the screenshot

    //Wait for one second 
    yield return waitForTime;
}
```

I did not encounter any problems by doing it this. Just start the coroutine and let it run forever in a while loop. It won't freeze because it is yielding every 1 second and also every frame. Below is the complete code:

```
public Camera camOV;
public RenderTexture currentRT;
float elapsedSecond = 0;
string screenshotsDirectory = "UnityHeadlessRenderingScreenshots";
float beginTime;

void Start()
{
    beginTime = Time.time;
    StartCoroutine(TakeScreenShot());
}

public IEnumerator TakeScreenShot()
{
    beginTime = Time.time;

    WaitForEndOfFrame waitForFrame = new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    WaitForSeconds waitForTime = new WaitForSeconds(1);//1 second

    while (true)
    {
        //Wait for frame
        yield return waitForFrame;

        //Increment timer
        elapsedSecond = Time.time - beginTime;

        RenderTexture.active = camOV.targetTexture;
        camOV.Render();
        Debug.Log(camOV);
        Texture2D imageOverview = new Texture2D(camOV.targetTexture.width, camOV.targetTexture.height,
            TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        imageOverview.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, camOV.targetTexture.width, camOV.targetTexture.height), 0, 0);
        imageOverview.Apply();
        RenderTexture.active = currentRT;

        // Encode texture into PNG
        byte[] bytes = imageOverview.EncodeToPNG();

        // save in memory
        string filename = elapsedSecond + ".png";
        var path = screenshotsDirectory + "/" + filename;
        File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);

        //Wait for one second 
        yield return waitForTime;

        Debug.Log(elapsedSecond);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, it seems (as we found with our project) that the execution doesn't get past yield return waitForFrame; when in headless mode

Comment: Did you copy this code as it is or did you modify it? Can you run it without modifying any piece of it?

Comment: I said this because the behavior you described usually when you don't start coroutine properly. It should be `StartCoroutine(TakeScreenShot());` not `TakeScreenShot()`. Anyways, make sure that the code is not modifiled.

Comment: No, I didn't modify the code, though I was running it in Unity 2017. If I run it in 5.6, it DOES advance, however it will only render two unique screenshots. The third screenshot onwards are the same as the second

Comment: I use 5.6 and I think you should stick with it for this problem so that we will both be on the-same page. Could you send me the project. If possible create new project with this problem, upload it somewhere and provide new link for it here. I will take a look at it.

Comment: Absolutely, I agree. You can find the project here: wetransfer.com/downloads/95474c2f85a6a0c2c69a5acffa150e0c20170519155635/06297d

Comment: Link is invalid

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/95474c2f85a6a0c2c69a5acffa150e0c20170519155635/06297d Sorry, try now? The shortened version is we.tl/0NgOViOSQS

Comment: Like I said. Use 5.6. You saved that project with 2017.

Comment: I ran/built/saved this project in 5.6, it should have converted it from 2017. I shall make another now.

Comment: You can't downgrade from Major versions but you can upgrade. Unity might let you do so but you will run into many problems. I want to make sure I am not wasting my time testing this while something else is the problem. Unity is currently warning me about that. Create a simple project with 5.6 with the code and see if the problem exist. If it does then zip that and send it.

Comment: Here is a fresh version in 5.6: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2422cf80798637de6b5c4ccd322a068520170519161837/1ffd14

Comment: were you able to download the 5.6 project ok?

Comment: I was able to replicate that problem. I am looking deeply into this. Check back in about 2 hours

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I tried using Camera.DiscardContents(), RenderTexture.Release(), GL.Clear() and .Flush() after the screenshot is taken to no avail

Comment: I am afraid to say that this is a bug. After extensive experiment each day, I realized that this affects UI components and Particles only. It does not affect  normal GameObject. Try it. A GameObject with a MeshRenderer or a Cube will be moving but the particle won't. I tried every thing to see if there is a workaround but nope. I didn't find one.

Comment: WOW! You're not wrong! Just reproduced that exactly. I shall accept this answer. Please feel free to add a small explanation re. finding out that its a bug, to your answer. Many thanks for your help with this, it has been very much appreciated.

Comment: I am still not done finding for a workaround. If I can't by the end of today then I will give up and modify the answer as a bug. I usually find a workaround when there is a bug but this one is totally different. Meanwhile, I suggest you file for a bug report at this time. From the Editor, Help-->Report a Bug....