# Unity: Unable to take screenshots in server build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to take snapshots in the server build of my Unity application. I am assuming that taking snapshots in headless/server builds is possible based on some posts online.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071756/run-unity-standalone-in-headless-mode-whilst-capturing-screenshots), I read that in headless mode, calling `camera.Render()` is necessary for rendering. I changed my screenshot logic accordingly.

Here is my script

```
private IEnumerator TakeSnapshot()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    var tempTexture = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(Screen.width, Screen.height);
    camOV.targetTexture = tempTexture;
    camOV.Render();
    
    var tex = new Texture2D(tempTexture.width, tempTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

    // Read screen contents into the texture
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, tempTexture.width, tempTexture.height), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();
    RenderTexture.active = tempTexture;

    // Encode texture into PNG
    var bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
    snapshotBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    // File.WriteAllBytes("/Users/varun/Desktop/" + Time.time + ".png", bytes);
    Destroy(tex);  
}
```

I initalize the camera in the Start() method

```
    camOV = Camera.main;
```

This works fine inside the editor but once I create a server build for Mac and try to run it I get this error and the output image is all grey.

```
ReadPixels was called to read pixels from system frame buffer, while not inside drawing frame.
 #0 ???
 #1 operator delete[](void*, std::nothrow_t const&)
 #2 operator delete[](void*, std::nothrow_t const&)
 #3 operator delete[](void*, std::nothrow_t const&)
 #4 operator delete[](void*, std::nothrow_t const&)
 #5  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.Texture2D:ReadPixelsImpl_Injected (UnityEngine.Texture2D,UnityEngine.Rect&,int,int,bool)
```

Can someone give any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: According to the error you are running on a wrong thread. How do you start this coroutine? From which context?

Comment: @YuriNudelman Thanks for the reply. I call it from the update function of another MonoBehaviour script when a certain condition is met. The code is working in the Unity editor but not working in the server build. Is it really wrong thread issue?

Comment: After some investigation, the error is due to trying to read pixels from screen (and not render texture). To read pixels from render texture, you also need to set `RenderTexture.active = tempTexture`. After that though you will have another error saying your graphic device is null. And this makes sense, there is no reason to initialize DirectX in headless mode. Bottom line I believe the post you cited is misleading - there is no reason for video memory being available in headless mode. Server may not have a graphic card at all actually. I have found no other evidence it is possible.

Comment: @YuriNudelman Thanks for the response. So are you saying that taking snapshots in headless/server mode isn't possible? Or is it not possible only if there is no Graphics card? Because right now I am trying to run the server build on my Macbook. I haven't deployed it to a server yet. And that's when I am getting this error.

Comment: What I am saying it is not possible or at least I didn't find any evidence of someone ever successfully doing it.

Comment: @YuriNudelman I see, thanks for the response!

Comment: You should maybe take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb it's emulating a screen server side, I have used it successfully with a chromium running server side